# How to edit a file in a new tab?

Tags: command-line, user-commands

I want to map `:e file.txt` to `:tabnew file.txt`, or the equivalent setting for editing file in a new tab. What do I need to put into my vimrc?

Comment: Are you aware that vim tabs are not the same as tabs in other applications? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers and in particular the first answer which I can only agree with: "Trying to beat Vim into 1 tab == 1 buffer is an exercise in futility."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to read [`:h user-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user-commands) and put the following in your vimrc:

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=file E tabnew <args>
```

You can't override `:e` but you can create the command `:E` which will take one argument (`-nargs=1`), complete this argument as `tabnew` does (`-complete=file`) and executes `tabnew` with the argument it took.

However as @Hotschke said in comments you probably don't need such a command.

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone else, I recommend pretty strongly against doing this, but if you're dead set on the idea (and for future readers who might be doing something slightly different) you could use something like:

```
:cabbrev <expr> e getcmdline() == 'e' && getcmdtype() == ':' ? 'tabnew' : 'e'
```

This will replace `:e` with `:tabnew` as soon as you type the space after the `e`. If you find the change too visually jarring, you could perhaps instead set up the the `E` command from [statox's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17768/343) and convert `:e` into `:E` instead.

See `:help :cabbrev` for more details.